# Change Password and Forgot Password with ParseUser in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on an application using Parse.com as backend support.I have used **ParseUser** for **login** and **signup** ,but now I have to implement **change Password** and **forgot password** ,but don't know how to implement it..Please help me to implement this functionalities.

The code which I have used to login the ParseUser is as follows:

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(str_email2, str_password2, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            dlg.dismiss();
            if(e == null)
            {
                Log.d(">>>","ObjId>>"+user.getObjectId()+"  Username>>>"+user.getUsername());

            }
            else
                loginUnSuccessful();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To request a new password (in case the user forgot it) you can use this:

```
ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground("myemail@example.com",
                                           new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // An email was successfully sent with reset instructions.
    } else {
      // Something went wrong. Look at the ParseException to see what's up.
    }
  }
});
```

And to change a password you can just get the current user and do the following:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.setPassword("new_password");
currentUser.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 4):

In the doc, you have this sample code:

```
ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground("myemail@example.com",
                                           new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // An email was successfully sent with reset instructions.
    } else {
      // Something went wrong. Look at the ParseException to see what's up.
    }
  }
});
```

Source: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-resetting

Comment: Is ``"myemail@example.com"`` the email you're sending the request to?

Answer (score 3):

You can not reset the password for not signed (anonymous) ParseUser.

If you are **using email feature** for ParseUser, you can send password reset mail like this

```
ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground(
   stringEmail,
   new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
     public void done(ParseException e) {
       ...
     }
   }
);
```

If you are **not using email feature**, you need to write a cloud method in your `main.js` file, like this

```
Parse.Cloud.define("resetPassword", function (request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); /*important*/
    var username = request.params.username;
    var password = request.params.password;
    var objUser = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var qUser = new Parse.Query(objUser);
    qUser.equalTo("username", username);
    qUser.find().then(function (resultObj) {
        if(resultObj.length > 0){
            var userObj = resultObj[0];
          userObj.set("password", password);
          return userObj.save();
        } else {
          response.error("User does not exist");
        }
    }).then(function () {
        response.success("Password RESET DONE SUCCESSFULLY");
    }, function (error) {
        response.error("Error " + error);
    });
});
```

and call that method from your app, like this

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("password", password);
params.put("username", username);
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("resetPassword", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void done(String response, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ...
        } else {
            ..
        }
    }
});
```

This way you can reset user password **using username or mobile number**.