# Validate user inputted password against user password saved on parse server before changing password

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform, parse-server

I am working on an application using Parse.com as backend support.I have implemented change Password using this code

```
if (pwdController!.text == newpwdController!.text)     {
user.password = pwdController!.text;
await user.save();
```

I want the user to enter the current password before allowing them change it to a new one but when I try to get the current password from the parseuser object it returns null, all the other similar questions I've seen such as this [Change Password and Forgot Password with ParseUser in Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668644/change-password-and-forgot-password-with-parseuser-in-parse-com) aren't validating that the user has the correct current password. How can I validate that the password entered by user is their current password before letting them change it?

Comment: You should check to see if the Flutter SDK has an equivalent method on ParseUser to http://parseplatform.org/Parse-Swift/release/documentation/parseswift/parseuser/verifypassword(password:usingpost:options:)

Comment: If you use a backend service you would want to check the response that you get. When the user writes the password and submits it and its wrong your going to get a response, then in your submit button you can put the conditions that if the response you got was 204(changed password), than move on, but if the response your getting is not right than display an error message. So just use the response you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify that the user has entered the correct current password by calling the ParseUser.login method with the username and entered password. Then check if it returns a successful response.

```
ParseUser user = await ParseUser.currentUser();// this gets the current user object
var nuser = (user.username, oldpwdController!.text,     user.username);


var resp = await nuser.login();
if (resp.success) {
user.password = pwdController!.text;
await user.save();
```

The snippet of code above assumes that you have two textcontrollers(oldpwdController for current password, and pwdController for new password to change to).